# Control how much influenced by its vertices a mesh will be (how much tight / loose will be)

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I created a number of meshes applying sveral modifiers. When creating in one of them o hole in the center I encountered an issue. I would like to make geometry of the vertices marked with red arrows to be influenced by their vertices **as loose** as those marked with the green arrows (the geometry is in -Edit Mode- in the big image). You can see why in the little image. When entering -Object Mode- the vertices of the hole creted in the mesh end up pinched. While the modifiers actions works as desired with the rest of the gemetry (The "loose" one). In other sofware like Maya, you can control per vertex how loose/tight a mesh will be to its vertex. I'm pretty much a newbie in blender. Any help will be much appreciated.

(I'm using Blender 2.83)[image: Both Modes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change to edge mode and select the edges nearby
and press shift + E and the edges will become purple and will tighten
you can also just press N and select the edges and change the mean crease

[image]

Comment: PERFECT !!  It worked out just smooth and easy. J Block, thank a lot !